# examples of matrix which cannot be triangulated

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, field-theory

I heard we cannot always triangulate matrix.

In a algebraically closed field, we can always triangulate matrix.

But what about other cases?

I would like to know examples of matrix which cannot be triangulated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Triangulated means turned into upper or lower triangular form by way of row operations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example,

$$\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1 \\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$

is not triangularisable over $\mathbb{R}$. Indeed, a matrix is triangularisable iff its characteristic polynomial is split.

Comment: Thank you very much. Is that sufficient and necessary condition? Could you tell me precise reason why matrix is triangularisable iff its characteristic polynomial is split? （sorry to bother..）.

Comment: Yes, this is an sufficient and necessary condition, which is also equivalent to "the minimal polynomial is split". The necessary part is easy (just triangularise the matrix and you see that the characteristic polynomial must be split). For the sufficient part, you can make an induction over the dimension, the key-point being to deduce from the fact that the characteristic polynomial is split that the matrix has at least one eigenvalue.